mallocで確保した分の領域外へのアクセス
気になっていること
c言語で、自作パケットを作成しています。
その時にパケットの名前を可変長で定義したいなぁと思っていました。
解決策の1つに、
char protocol_name[1] 　のように定義して、strncpyで好きな文字列を入れてあげる方法を見つけました。
データ壊れるでしょ？！あり得ないと思い検証実験を行いました。
検証実験の内容
mallocで取得したサイズより大きくなるように、長い文字列を入れることでどのような挙動になるかを実験しました。
以下が実際ののコードです。
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    uint8_t num1;
    char text[1];
    uint8_t num2;
} test_struct;

int main() {
    // Allocate memory for the struct
    test_struct *ptr = (test_struct *)malloc(sizeof(test_struct));
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to allocate memory.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Initialize the struct fields
    ptr->num1 = 10;
    strncpy(ptr->text, "hello", 5); // Copy "hello" into text field
    ptr->num2 = 20;

    // Print the struct data
    printf("num1: %d\n", ptr->num1);
    printf("text: %s\n", ptr->text);
    printf("num2: %d\n", ptr->num2);

    // Free the allocated memory
    free(ptr);

    return 0;
}


実行結果は以下のようになりました。
$ gcc -o test test.c
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:22:5: warning: ‘__builtin_memcpy’ writing 5 bytes into a region of size 2 overflows the destination [-Wstringop-overflow=]
   22 |     strncpy(ptr->text, "hello", 5); // Copy "hello" into text field
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.c:14:39: note: at offset 1 into destination object of size 3 allocated by ‘malloc’
   14 |     test_struct *ptr = (test_struct *)malloc(sizeof(test_struct));
      |                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
$ ./test
num1: 10
text: hllo
num2: 20

コンパイラでエラーが出るものの、きちんとコンパイルは通りました。
さらに、helloのeがおかしくなっていますが、きちんと表示できています。
知りたいこと
この時メモリがどのようになっているのかが知りたいです。
なぜデータが壊れないのか、メモリ内のデータの配置はどうなっているのか想像はできますが、なぜポインタできちんと表示できるのか教えていただければ幸いです。
注意書き
DCL38-C. フレキシブル配列メンバには正しい構文を使用する
要素数1の配列を定義して、私のように使うことはバッファフローを引き起こすので、絶対にしてはいけないことの一例です。
悪い例として、見ていただけたら幸いです。
コメントで教えてくださった方々ありがとうございました。

質問項目にないのでコメントで。本来の使い方が別にあるのだと思います。
[1]の一般的な利用方法, の GNU C 拡張に 長さゼロの配列(Arrays of Length Zero)があるので使い方の参考になるかも

C99でフレキシブル配列メンバーが追加されたので、未定義動作である要素数1や独自拡張の要素数0は使うべきではないと思います。

ありがとうございます。　[1]の配列を定義することは、絶対にやってはいけないことと教授に言われました。　奥が深いなぁとワクワクしています。

データは壊れており、元の文字列に近い文字列が表示されるのは、偶然です。
1バイトずつダンプすれば分かると思います。
# ./test | od -c -t d1 -
0000000    n    u    m    1    :         1    0   \n    t    e    x    t    :         h
         110  117  109   49   58   32   49   48   10  116  101  120  116   58   32  104
0000020  024    l    l    o    7   \n    n    u    m    2    :         2    0   \n
          20  108  108  111   55   10  110  117  109   50   58   32   50   48   10
0000037

上記の通り、"hello"の2バイト目が（ptr->num2 = 20;の）20（ASCIIだと制御文字）で上書きされているので、見方によっては"e"が消えているように見えます。
3バイト目以降が元の通り表示され（ているように見え）るのは、偶然です。

メモリがどうなっているかは、printfで1バイトずつダンプすれば分かります。
https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/sjd3rq6f8
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    uint8_t num1;
    char text[1];
    uint8_t num2;
} test_struct;

void dump_text(const char *text, size_t size)
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i ) {
        printf("0x%2x(%3u) ", text[i], text[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    // Allocate memory for the struct
    test_struct *ptr = (test_struct *)malloc(sizeof(test_struct));
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to allocate memory.\n");
        return 1;
    }
dump_text(ptr->text, 6);

    // Initialize the struct fields
    ptr->num1 = 10;
    strncpy(ptr->text, "hello", 5); // Copy "hello" into text field
dump_text(ptr->text, 6);
    ptr->num2 = 20;
dump_text(ptr->text, 6);

    // Print the struct data
    printf("num1: %d\n", ptr->num1);
    printf("text: %s\n", ptr->text);
    printf("num2: %d\n", ptr->num2);

    // Free the allocated memory
    free(ptr);

    return 0;
}

Program stdout:
0x 0(  0) 0x 0(  0) 0x 0(  0) 0x 0(  0) 0x 0(  0) 0x 0(  0) 
0x68(104) 0x65(101) 0x6c(108) 0x6c(108) 0x6f(111) 0x 0(  0) 
0x68(104) 0x14( 20) 0x6c(108) 0x6c(108) 0x6f(111) 0x 0(  0) 
num1: 10
text: hllo
num2: 20


ダンプする考えはなかったです。
こうしてみると、ちゃんと理解できた感じがします。　メモリの勉強しなければいけないなぁと思いました、、、、

alphaさんの回答に補足です。
malloc()等のメモリアロケータは要求されたメモリサイズちょうどではなく、管理がしやすいようにある程度の単位サイズで管理します。一例としてglibcのmallocのコメントには
  Minimum allocated size: 4-byte ptrs:  16 bytes    (including 4 overhead)
                          8-byte ptrs:  24/32 bytes (including, 4/8 overhead)

       When a chunk is freed, 12 (for 4byte ptrs) or 20 (for 8 byte
       ptrs but 4 byte size) or 24 (for 8/8) additional bytes are
       needed; 4 (8) for a trailing size field and 8 (16) bytes for
       free list pointers. Thus, the minimum allocatable size is
       16/24/32 bytes.

       Even a request for zero bytes (i.e., malloc(0)) returns a
       pointer to something of the minimum allocatable size.

       The maximum overhead wastage (i.e., number of extra bytes
       allocated than were requested in malloc) is less than or equal
       to the minimum size, except for requests >= mmap_threshold that
       are serviced via mmap(), where the worst case wastage is 2 *
       sizeof(size_t) bytes plus the remainder from a system page (the
       minimal mmap unit); typically 4096 or 8192 bytes.

と説明されています。他の実装でもなんらか最低サイズは存在します。
質問のコードではmalloc()に3バイト要求していますが、最低でも12バイト確保されています。受け取ったプログラムは7バイトしか書き込んでいないので、malloc()の管理領域も破壊していません。

なるほど、、、　初めて知りました。
mallocの仕様も関係してくるのですね。　悪用できそうな気もしますね、、、、

この辺の目に見えにくいメモリ破壊問題は C や C++ の弱点（後発言語に対して）なので、ベンダさんもいろいろチェック機構を強化してきています。
例えば Windows 用の Visual Studio では Debug ビルドするとメモリ破壊チェックルーチンが呼ばれるようになり

のようにエラー表示が出るものもあります。残念ながら壊したその場で出るわけではなくて、いくつかあるチェックポイントを通過したときにこのようなエラー表示となります。
他には gcc や visual c++ 等では -fsanitize=address コンパイルオプションが使えたりします。 VS2019 C++ のプロパティページの例

同様のメモリ破壊系質疑応答の例 malloc(sizeof(char))→10000要素の配列を作れてしまうのはなぜですか？ 残念ながら cygwin64 では sanitize library が欠損している様子。
C/C++ では、誤ったプログラムであっても一見正しく動いてしまうことがある（エラーにならない）あたりがいやらしいっスね。
C : 配列の添字について

いやらしいですねぇ、、、　そこまで考えれるようになりたいです、、、
